# Kruskal-Wallis test vs. ANOVA in SAS with complex survey data?

Tags: sas, anova

I am analyzing a temporal trend(`yr`) of certain chemicals(`a b & c`).
I use `proc sgplot` and `series` statement to draw a plot and found there was a decreasing trend.
Becuase the data is right-skewed, I used the median concentration of each year to draw the plot.

Now I would like to conduct a statistical test on the trend. My data came from the NHANES and need to use the `proc survey**` to perform analysis. I know I can do an ANOVA test based on `proc surveyreg` and use `ANOVA` option in the `MODEL`statement.

```
proc suveyreg data=a;
   stratum stra;
   cluster clus;
   weight wt;
   model a=yr/anova;
run;
```

But since the original data is right-skewed, I think maybe it is better to use Kruskal-Wallis test on the original data. But I don't know how to write a code in SAS and I didn't find information in `proc survey**`-related document.

My plan B is to use the log-transformed data and ANOVA test. But I am not sure if that is an appropriate approach. Can somebody tell me how to get the normality test of the residual in ANOVA while using `proc surveyreg`? I would also like to know if I can test a b & c in one procedure or I should write multiple procedures with changes in `MODEL` statement.

Looking forward to your engagement.Thank you!

Comment: I'd post this in the Stats forum on communities.sas.com

Comment: I already post it on communities.sas.com and I will update this if someone provides information there. But I asked differently because I think maybe ANOVA is better.